# Standardize log data in ELK - Elastic Logstash Kibana

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm using ELK for log managment.

What is the best practice for manage log level. In one log its lower case at the other its bigger case.

[image]

Where is the best place to resolve this?

- At the logstash?
- At Elastic DB?
- Kibana while execute the query?

And how?

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions:

1. normalize the string value.  Whether it's "DEBUG", "Debug" or "debug" is up to you.
2. add a [numerical equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog#Severity_level).

This way, you can run queries like: "severity_num:<=3" to get the bad stuff and then use the string "severity" field in the display.

More details [here](http://svops.com/blog/handling-log-levels-in-logstash/).

Comment: Where in the flow should I normalize? and how? This was my issue. But all the other info is great!

Comment: My logstash config is separated into many smaller files, which logstash combines alphabetically.  I put cleanup stuff like this in one of the later files.  See the linked blog posting for actual configs.